# Modal operator to highlight

Tags: python, opengl

Ok. I'm a bit stuck on this. I accept defeat and am asking for advice. Here is a portion of the larger addon. The purpose of this snippet is to show the area user is working on. Basically, user inputs index of an objects face, which gets highlighted using bgl. While I managed to highlight a face, I can't seem to get the panel to work, it gets locked during the modal operation. Here is the script:

```
import bpy
import bgl
import bmesh
from bpy.props import *
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d as loc3d2d

def initialise():
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    ob = bpy.context.active_object
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data)
    mw = ob.matrix_world
    face_count = len([face for face in bm.faces])-1
    bpy.types.WindowManager.face_index = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Ind", default=0, max=face_count)
    face = bpy.types.WindowManager.face_index
    return(scene, ob, bm, mw, face)

def draw_overlay(bm, context):
    wm = context.window_manager
    idx = wm.face_index
    ob = context.active_object
    mw = ob.matrix_world
    region = context.region
    rv3d = context.space_data.region_3d
    verts = [v.co for v in bm.faces[idx].verts]

    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_QUADS)
    bgl.glColor4f(0.2, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2)    

    for coord in verts:
        vector3d = mw * coord
        vector2d = loc3d2d(region, rv3d, vector3d) # returns a 2-tuple
        bgl.glVertex2f(*vector2d) # needs a 2d vector to draw to 2d screen
    bgl.glEnd()

    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_QUADS)
    return

class visualizeFace(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Visualize selected face. Face select by index."""
    bl_idname = "view3d.visualise_face"
    bl_label = "Show Face"

    index = IntProperty(name="IDX", default=0)

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        if event.type in {'MIDDLEMOUSE', 'WHEELUPMOUSE', 'WHEELDOWNMOUSE'}:
            # allow navigation
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            return {'FINISHED'}
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        elif event.type in ('RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'):
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        scene, ob, bm, mw, face = initialise()

        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            args = (bm, context)
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_overlay, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, 
            "View3D not found, cannot run operator")

            return {'CANCELLED'}

class IndexFace(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'
    bl_label = "Visualize Face"

    def draw(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(wm, "face_index")
        row.operator(visualizeFace.bl_idname, text="RUN")

def register():
    bpy.types.WindowManager.face_index = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Ind", default=0)
    bpy.utils.register_class(visualizeFace)
    bpy.utils.register_class(IndexFace)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(visualizeFace)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(IndexFace)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.face_index

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Line 82 should be `self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_overlay, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')`  Think the issue here is you invoke the the operator with the points of one face.  You could really just pass bm and context as callback args and get the window_manager and edit_object from context in the callback.

Comment: Hello, batFINGER! I'm pleased to see You! Not sure I followed Your thought in last sentence. You mean "def draw_overlay(bm, context):" ? And then somewhere in draw_overlay I should state: wm = context.window_manager and get self.index and list of verts. Correct?

Comment: Yes................

Comment: Ok, done all of that. Added necessary variables in draw_overlay. No errors. Index is taken from window_manager. It works the same way, no improvements.I can't seem to leftmouse in the TOOL_PROPS panel to change the setting, even if I add the event of leftmouse to pass_through.

Comment: Oh, dear, oh, dear! Am I one d*mb son of a gun... Two weeks spent on this problem and, as it turned out, it was as simple as setting {'FINISHED'} on LEFTMOUSE event in modal(). Revised script in the original post.